# How to prevent EF Core Code First from scaffolding SQL Server Views

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I know SQL Server views are supported in EF Core.  Using the code first approach, EF Core 7 keeps scaffolding my SQL Server Views.  I do not want it to.  The only way I've been able to accomplish this it to use

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<LogBudgetView>();
```

I then have to comment that out after scaffolding because if I don't then EF Core won't recognize my view when I try to use it which is annoying.  Any idea how I can get EF Core to STOP scaffolding my SQL Server Views?

My code...

```
public class LogBudgetView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; } = null!;
...

public virtual DbSet<LogBudgetView> LogBudgetViews { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // views
    modelBuilder.Entity<LogBudgetView>().ToView("vwBudgetLog").HasKey(x => x.Id);
    //modelBuilder.Ignore<LogBudgetView>();
    ...
```

Comment: Use EF Core Power Tools, has a simple UI for choosing objects

Comment: You could use a DbContext subtype that ignores the views to generate migrations.  Or conditionally ignore them in your OnModelCreating.  For migrations you'll normally startup with a parameterless constructor.